# Cannot convert source type to target type compilation error

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

I have this simple class

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        ClassB<ClassA> objA = new ClassB<ClassA>();

        ClassB<ITestA<MyDTO>> objB = new ClassB<ClassA>();

    }
}


public class ClassB<T>
{
    ///some code here
}


public interface ITestA<T>
{
    ///some code here
}

public class MyDTO
{
    ///some code here
}

public class ClassA : ITestA<MyDTO>
{
    ///some code 
}
```

This line of code

```
ClassB<ITestA<MyDTO>> objB = new ClassB<ClassA>();
```

is giving compilation error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'ClassB<ClassA>' to 'ClassB<ITestA<MyDTO>>
```

Since ClassA implements ITestA, I don't know why would this give a compilation error. Please help me understand what am I doing wrong.

Thanks,
Esen

Comment: Variance is only supported for interfaces.  You can't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's due to a rather complex feature of generics called [variance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Classes are invariant, which means that if you declare `ClassB<T>`, then when creating an instance:

```
ClassB<T1> obj = new ClassB<T2>
```

Then `T1` has to be exactly the same class as `T2`.

You can use interfaces to get around this, eg change your code to the following and it'll compile:

```
...
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassB<ClassA> objA = new ClassB<ClassA>();

        IClassB<ITestA<MyDTO>> objB = new ClassB<ClassA>();

    }
}


public interface IClassB<out T>  // <- note the out before T
{
    //some code here
}
public class ClassB<T> : IClassB<T>
{
    //some code here
}
...
```

In this case, `IClassB` is declared as covariant, which means that it can handle being given a derived class of `T`, rather than needing `T` itself. There are risks around using covariance (and contravariance) though, which is why generic classes are invariant by default.