# Decorator pattern and generics

Tags: c#, generics, decorator, proxy-pattern

Regular interface:

```
public interface IComputation
{
    void Reset();
    float GetValue1();
    float GetValue2();  
}
```

Generic interface:

```
public interface IComputation<T> : IComputation where T : IComputation
{
    T Proxy { get; set; }
}
```

Now for the classes:

```
public abstract class Computation<T> : IComputation<T> where T : IComputation
{
    public T Proxy { get; set; }    
}
```

Class 'ComputationCache' is a 'decorated" computation:

```
internal abstract class ComputationCache<T> : IComputation where T : IComputation
{
    public T Proxy { get; set; }    

    public float GetValue1()
    {
        bool isCached = //check cache.
        if(!isCached)
        {
            //compute value
            float value1 = Proxy.GetValue1();                           

            //update cache

            return value;
        }       
    }
}
```

To initialize the decorated computation, I tried the following:

```
public ComputationCache(IComputation<T> proxy)
{
    Proxy = (T) proxy;
    proxy.Proxy = this;
}
```

...which gives the following error":

> Cannot convert source type 'ComputationCache' to target type 'T'.

Can someone comment on whether it is better to use:

```
ComputationCache<T> : IComputation where T : IComputation
```

vs

```
ComputationCache<T> : IComputation<T> where T : IComputation
```

Comment: Your abstraction looks bit overkill

Comment: I've to say that you lost me

Comment: @Rahul. The classes shown above are abstract, and are sub-classed by multiple Computation"s, along with corresponding "ComputationCache"s that derive from base cache class. I'm trying to avoid repeated casting of the 'Proxy' property at the lower levels of the hierarchy.

Comment: You can solve the error by using `proxy.Proxy = (T) (IComputation)this;` but yeah... Overkill for this kind of abstraction is the right word. What is your `IComputation<T>`- Interface good for?

Comment: Why, what is the reason for that kind of wrapper on wrapper???

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use:

```
ComputationCache<T> : IComputation<T> where T : IComputation
```

If you want to use your cache as a `IComputation<T>` and have access to its `Proxy` property.

Second, for your error:

> Cannot convert source type 'ComputationCache' to target type 'T'.

Just do this:

```
proxy.Proxy = (T)(IComputation)this;
```

*(I don't know why there is this error. Since ComputationCache is a IComputation, like T...)*

---

**EDIT: Well I found something that makes my solution wrong:**

```
new ComputationCache<Computation<IComputation>>(new Computation<Computation<IComputation>>());
```

This post helped to find this error about [Generics variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31148496/cannot-convert-source-type-to-target-type-compilation-error)

`T` becomes `Computation<IComputation>` that isn't equal to the `ComputationCache` type.

You will probably have some troubles to make working your `Proxy` property as you wrote it.

You may want to do something like that then:

```
public interface IComputation
{
    IComputation Proxy { get; set; }
    // Other stuff
}

public interface IComputation<T> : IComputation where T : IComputation
{
    new T Proxy { get; set; }
    // Other stuff
}
```

But you will have to manage the two properties `Proxy`.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but it's a start.